# Xcode code snippet for class continuation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, code-snippets

I have an Xcode (4.6) code snippet for creating properties – one for weak, one for strong properties:

[image: Weak/strong property snippet in the Xcode code snippet editor]

Typing `propstrong` works nicely in the interface declaration (.h file), but **doesn’t offer me the snippet when I do it in the class continuation:**

```
@interface MyClass ()
```

`propstrong`   // nothing happens :(

```
@end
```

I have tried all the completion scopes in the snippet editor (even “All”), to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you change the completion shortcut to 'propstrong' (e.g. remove the .m - that may confuse things).

Comment: I don't think `.m` files are related to Objective-C++, please try to select Objective-C if you are going to use snippet not only at `.h` but at `.m` files as well.

Comment: D'oh, I hadn’t noticed that the default selection was Objective-C++. Thanks, A-Live!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had mistakenly left the Language field at its strangely-default selection, Objective-C++. Change this to Objective-C, and the snippet works in class continuations.